# Entity Framework Relationships two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a Friendship mapping table that has 2 FK's that originate from the same class (User and SportsFacility)

Here are my model classes.

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AcountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    //[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CheckQueue> ChecksQueue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookedEvent> BookedEvents { get; set; }
}

public partial class SportsFacility
{
    public SportsFacility()
    {
        ChecksQueue = new List<CheckQueue>();
        BookedEvent = new List<BookedEvent>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PnH_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(70)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int City_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("City_Id")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CheckQueue> ChecksQueue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookedEvent> BookedEvent { get; set; }
}


public partial class CheckQueue
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartCheckTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CheckParams { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int User_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int SportsFacility_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SportsFacility_Id")]
    public virtual SportsFacility SportsFacility { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public DateTime? LastCheck { get; set; }
}

public partial class BookedEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime BookDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CheckParams { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int User_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int SportsFacility_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SportsFacility_Id")]
    public virtual SportsFacility SportsFacility { get; set; }
}
```

I tried override the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SportsFacility>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CheckQueue>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookedEvent>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

}

This causes a new error message to be displayed.

```
Additional information: The entity types 'BookedEvent' and 'CheckQueue' cannot share table 'CheckQueues' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your DbSets for duplicates.

Comment: You should probably rename all your Id fields to be unique to the entity they represent 
I.E. : UserId, SportsFacilityId, etc....

Comment: @DaniDev why? isnt `user.Id` easier to read than `user.UserId`? (and less redundant)